# Should I change my DB from MyISAM to InnoDB? (AWS notification)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am developing a browser app that connects to several MySQL-databases through php-sites. These databases are set on a single AWS RDS instance. When I set up these databases I was not very well informed about the different db engines. After reading about the different types I decided to use InnoDB for low IOPS demands and MyISAM for high IOPS demands as I read it was faster in certain tasks.

Amazon Web Services tells me that:

> DB Instance test-1 contains MyISAM tables that have not been migrated to InnoDB. These tables can impact your ability to perform point-in-time restores. Consider converting these tables to InnoDB. Please refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.BackingUpAndRestoringAmazonRDSInstances.html#Overview.BackupDeviceRestrictions

Should I recreate the MyISAM db using InnoDB?

Comment: The fact that MyISAM is faster is only really relevant if you large data throughput requirements - for most CRUD applications doing typical web-application workloads you're much better-off with InnoDB for its stronger resiliancy and greater feature-set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trope about MyISAM being faster than InnoDB is a holdover from code that was current in the mid-2000's.

MyISAM is *not* faster than InnoDB anymore, for most types of queries. Look at the benchmarks in this blog from 2007: https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/01/08/innodb-vs-myisam-vs-falcon-benchmarks-part-1/

InnoDB has just gotten better, faster, and more reliable since then. MyISAM is not being developed.

*Update:* In MySQL 8.0, even the system tables have been converted to InnoDB. There is clearly an intention to phase out MyISAM. I expect that it will be deprecated and then removed in future versions of MySQL (but I can't say how many years from now that will be).

There were a couple of edge cases where MyISAM might be faster, like table-scans. But you really shouldn't be optimizing your database for table-scans. You should be creating the right indexes to *avoid* table-scans.

> *Update Feb 2018:* MyISAM just suffered an additional 40% performance hit from the recent fix for the Meltdown CPU bug, and this affects table-scans. Assuming you are responsible and patch your systems to fix the Meltdown vulnerability, MyISAM is now a performance liability. See current tests of MyISAM performance with the patch: https://mariadb.org/myisam-table-scan-performance-kpti/

But what trumps that is the fact that InnoDB supports ACID behavior, and MyISAM doesn't support *any* of the four qualities of ACID. See my answer to [MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717)

Failing to support ACID isn't just an academic point. It translates into things like table-locks during updates, and global locks during backups.